# How to read String Builder line by line

Tags: java, string, io

Can I read String Builder line by line? And Get the length of each line as well.

---

**EDIT:**

"*I build string in StringBuilder and add "\n" within. And I need to read it again. I need to consider that every "\n" has a new line.*"

Comment: AFAIK, there's no concept of a _line_ in `StringBuilder`. It's just a sequence of characters. That being said, could you please elaborate?

Comment: i build string in StringBuilder and add "\n" within. And I need to read it again. I need to consider that every "\n" has a new line.

Comment: @Ran, Thanks, but that sort of information should have been in the initial question. It's a really important detail!

Comment: Oh. I should include it.. Sorry

Comment: @user647772 I have a StringBuilder full of data. I want to read it. Why is this difficult to comprehend?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given your edit, it's as simple as invoking [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29) on the `StringBuilder` instance, and then invoking [`split("\\n")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on the returned `String` instance. And from there, you'll have a `String` array that you can loop through to access each "line" of the `StringBuilder` instance. And of course, invoke [`length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) on each `String` instance, or "line" to get its length.

---

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("line 1");
sb.append("\\n");
sb.append("line 2");

String[] lines = sb.toString().split("\\n");
for(String s: lines){
    System.out.println("Content = " + s);
    System.out.println("Length = " + s.length());
}
```

Comment: @Ran, `split` returns a `String` array.

Comment: Can you give me example using this  String x = firstLayer.fullbinary.toString();
 x.split("\\n"); sorry im just a beginner.

Answer (score 15):

Make a Scanner object and there you can easily parse line for line and get the length.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(sb.toString()); // I have named your StringBuilder object sb
while (scan.hasNextLine() ){
 String oneLine = scan.nextLine();
 System.out.println(oneLine.length());
}
```

Comment: What is this: `String Builder object`?

Comment: @Tichodroma It's the reference variable name for the instance of the String Builder object he want's to process.

Comment: I don't think that's legal Java syntax.

Comment: I am absolutely sure it isn't :) I can change it to sb if you want but I wrote so due to pseudo code for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, in the simple case you can just use `toString().split()`. If you want something a bit more flexible and which also supports line removal, it's pretty straightforward to iterate over the lines by just keeping track of the start and end values of the last line that you returned:

```
    new Iterator<String>() {
      boolean hasNext = true;
      boolean removed = false;
      int start = 0;
      int end = -1;
      @Override public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
      }

      @Override public String next() {
        removed = false;
        if (!hasNext) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        start = end + 1;
        end = value.indexOf("\n", start);
        if (end == -1) {
          hasNext = false;
        }
        return value.substring(
            start,
            end == -1 ? value.length() : end);
      }

      @Override public void remove() {
        if (removed) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Multiple calls to remove() without and intervening call to next().");
        }
        value.delete(
            start,
            end == -1 ? value.length() : end + 1);
        end = start - 1;
        removed = true;
      }
    };
```

You can see this in a utility class that returns a LineIterator for String or StringBuilder here: http://pastebin.com/JA6abTg3

And it has tests which show how it can be used here: http://pastebin.com/X1b5cGX8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you can call [`toString().split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) on it to get an array. You can split on line delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I think there no method to read stringbuilder line by line.
but if you want to separate whole string by line than you may ad newline character ""\n"" when you append string in StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Use ("\n");, when you appending to stringbuilder.
This is the simple way of doing.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm replying several years later but ran into the same problem.

Instead of playing these games with Split(), etc. why not just build a list of strings?

```
Dim Lines = New List(of String)
Dim Length As Integer

Lines.Add("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.")
Lines.Add("The slow turtle crawled down the grassy lane.")

For Each Line in Lines
  Length = Line.Length
  Debug.WriteLine("Length = " + Length)
Next
```